# Web Audio API sound analyzer is glitching out

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm having a weird problem with the Web Audio API.

I'm playing a constant smooth sinewave, and it sounds perfect. But when I run it through an analyzer and make a visualization for it, it keeps glitching and twitching around even though I hear no change in the sound and nothing is happening besides the visualizer draw loop.

Sound:

```
oscillator1 -> gain1 -> |
oscillator2 -> gain2 -> | gain (master) -> analyser -> destination
```

in visualizer loop:

```
var bData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(bData);
//for loop in which I use "bData[i]" to get the bar heights//
```

Result:

[image: glitching sound analyzer]
Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it?

I'm using Firefox 27.0.1 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of a bug in Firefox, that I'm in the process of fixing, at the moment. Sorry about that.

This is the bug in question: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=848954